# Spring jpa duplication of record insertion exception on unique attributes

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

First time `personService.addPerson(person);` works fine when similar record inserted again it cast this exception:

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Patient' for key 'Role'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_112]"
```

I want to keep unique rows in database on the basis of email, role in `person` table (email) and in `personrole` table (role).

--Tables are

```
CREATE TABLE PersonRole(Role_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Role VARCHAR(50) unique);
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE Person(Person_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Email VARCHAR(50) unique);
```

--Person entity

```
@Entity

public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private int person_ID;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "Role_ID")
private Personrole personrole;
```

.............
--personrole entity

@Entity

```
public class Personrole implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private int role_ID;

@Column(length = 50)
private String role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "personrole",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Person> persons;
```

..............................
--here is my column

@Controller

```
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signUp(@Valid Person person, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("message", result.getAllErrors() + "\n DOB is: " + person.getDob());
        return "fail";
    }

    Date date = new Date();
    person.setRegister_Date(date);

    personService.addPerson(person);
```

---Thanks in advance---